# console values arent the same if it is expanded

Tags: console, firebug

In  firebug, does anyone know why the length = 0 in the first line and when I click on it to expand, it says that the length = 3.. Shouldnt both be equal? SAme goes with models:Array[0] but in the expand version it is Array[3]

[image: firebug screenshot]

Comment: while you console log it the length is zero then you added elements to it later.

Comment: Btw. your screenshot doesn't show Firebug but the Chrome DevTools. Furthermore note that hovering the little "i" at the end of the line also gives you this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console log captures the current state of the object, the later update of the object is reflected when you expand it. You can try in console the below to see how it behaves.

```
  var test = {length:0,models:[]};
   console.log(test);
   test.length =4;
```

Comment: How would I go about into getting the value of the later update.. That is the value that I want to assign to a variable..

Comment: You will get the value after the update happens. Are you updating the value after an ajax call? Give more details about your problem.